# Deploying an Azure Web App through Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy an Azure Web App through a Jenkins scripted pipeline using the [Azure App Service Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+App+Service+Plugin). This is my deploy-command (GUIDs have been changed):

```
azureWebAppPublish azureCredentialsId: 'a0774bb6-e471-47s9-92dc-5aa7b4t683e8', resourceGroup: 'my-demo-app', appName: 'MY-DEMO-APP', filePath: 'public/*, package.json'
```

When running the script I get the following error:

> The client '03a1b3f9-a6fb-48bd-b016-4e37ec712f14' with object id '03a1b3f9-a6fb-48bd-b016-4e37ec712f14' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope '/subscriptions/81fd39sw-3d28-454c-bc78-abag45r5d4d4/resourceGroups/my-demo-app/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MY-DEMO-APP' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The strange thing is, the ID of this "client" that's missing authorization does not appear anywhere in the build plan. It's neither the ID or a part of the service principal nor the ID of the Container Registry credentials. It also doesn't appear on the machine that executes the build (I checked both the GUID of the mother board and the windows installation). Also the term client is not used for any part of the build plan, so I don't really know what's the actual issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this tutorial that explains how to Set up continuous integration and deployment to Azure App Service with Jenkins and One of the best method to deploy to Azure Web App (Windows) from Jenkins : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/java-deploy-webapp-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To find the Azure AD user with the object id '03a1b3f9-a6fb-48bd-b016-4e37ec712f14', go to Azure portal, open Cloud Shell and run

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId '03a1b3f9-a6fb-48bd-b016-4e37ec712f14'
```

To diagnose or troubleshoot the issue, go to Azure Portal -> Resource Groups -> my-demo-app -> MY-DEMO-APP -> Access control (IAM) -> Role assignments -> and then search for above found AD User and check if that user has atleast read permission.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I stopped invsetigating this as the application in question will not stay as an Azure Web App in the long run, but I will look into it when I have some time.